# Bash create directories recursively without last

Tags: bash, mkdir, mkdirs

How can I ensure that intermidiate components exist? Something like `mkdir -p {}` but without last component?

Comment: Why don't you just do mkdir -p without the last component? Where are you getting your directory structure from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your path is `$f`

Just run `` mkdir -p `dirname $f` ``